# HttpContext.User.Identity.Name in a deployed application

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-mvc-2, authentication

For an ASP.NET MVC 2 application, we are using `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` to get the user name for authentication purposes. This works fine when testing. Users who are in the database are able to access areas for which they have permissons, and redirected to a 401 page otherwise. The 401 page displays their username, explaining that this user is not authorized to access this content.

However, in a deployed environment, all attempts to access any portion of the application redirect to the 401 page, and the displayed username is blank!

How can we enable the deployed application to access the username of the request?

From my research, I should go to the following screen and enable Windows Authentication, but it's not in the list!

[image]

Comment: What authentication scheme are you using? Windows Integrated? Forms?

Comment: Are you deploying to a server farm? I have run into issues when using session variables on a server farm.

Comment: We are currently testing with a deployment to the local machine.

Comment: How are you enforcing the authorization? You may need to disable anonymous authentication in your IIS application to force an authentication response from the browser.

Comment: @DavidNelson Tried that, got an IIS 401. `HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers.`

Comment: You definitely need anonymous authentication turned off, or every user will come through as anonymous. If you use a non-IE browser, do you get prompted for credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, if you are using IIS 7, you probably need to install it first! [Here's a good overview.](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication) FTA:

> The default installation of IIS 7 does not include the Windows
>   authentication role service. To use Windows authentication on IIS, you
>   must install the role service, disable Anonymous authentication for
>   your Web site or application, and then enable Windows authentication
>   for the site or application.

If you're not seeing it as an option, you probably don't have it installed.

(Dictated from my Winodws 7 machine,) Go to your Start menu and type: *Turn Windows features on or off*.

Next, in the dialog's treeview, go to *Internet Information Services - World Wide Web Services - Security* and then check the ***Windows Authentication*** checkbox.

Comment: Thanks! I had discovered this information, and *just* finished getting it all to work when you posted this! I just needed to turn the Windows feature on to get it into the list.

Answer (score 2):

We had an issue like this to, what we ended up doing was turning off Anonymous Access in IIS. Remember to check the Integrated box at the bottom.. Hope this helps

Comment: "Integrated box at the bottom" - bottom of what?

Comment: Of the Anon Access Window in IIS.. Please let me know if you have not seen this before.

Comment: I have not. Turns out I just had to disable Anonymous Access and enable Windows. The biggest obstacle was that Windows was not in the list, and the feature had to be turned on (see accepted answer).